# amazon s3 deletion not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want to delete a specif object from amazone s3. i am doing with this code

```
    $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => CONTENT_KEY,
    'secret' => CONTENT_SECRET
    ));
    $keyname     = /Testing/test_mag120/hhhhhh427/;
    $result = $s3->deleteObjects(array(
    'Bucket'  => CONTENT_BUCKET,
    'Objects' => array(
    array('Key' => $keyname),

    )
));



    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    die();
```

when i print the output i got this

```
  Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object
  (
[structure:protected] => 
[data:protected] => Array
    (
        [Deleted] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Key] => /Testing/test_mag120/hhhhhh427/
                    )

            )

        [RequestId] => dumbdata
    )

  )
```

After i log in to this account through s3 browser then the  object is not deleted. if this is any permission issue. if any one know about this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had issues when trying to do this before. For the bucket name do not provide s3://, instead just provide your bucket name. For the key name, do not include a "/" first, so for example you may have the following file. Note, key does not me accessKey, but instead name of the file. Also delete must be done on a file, not a directory. S3 does not have actual directorys like windows.

S3://myBucket/myFile.csv

You would want to provide

Bucket = myBucket

Key = myFile.csv

so maybe try(but this doesn't seem to be a specific file?"...

```
 $keyname     = Testing/test_mag120/hhhhhh427/;
```

Comment: If the key name was specified incorrectly then you should have seen a 404 response.